# Provide a "grace period" to undo/retract bounty assignments (in case of misclicks)

Tags: feature-request, status-review, bounty, user-experience

When you upvote or downvote on something, you have a few minutes to change your mind. But when you award a bounty, it's just one click and it's done. There isn't even a confirmation!

I've just misclicked on the wrong answer (because it popped up at the top of the answers list), and ended up awarding the bounty to the wrong person, and I feel terribly bad about it.

Thanks to [a generous gift from rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424830/bounty-assignment-retraction-grace-period#comment958767_424830), this *specific* case has been addressed, but I still think that a grace period to retract/undo assignment of a bounty would be a nice feature to add to the site.

Obviously, to prevent abuse, the grace period should be short. It could  even be like that for comment upvotes, where refreshing the page clears the grace period. The idea is to cater for users who misclick. On mobile devices, where clicking is actually tapping, misclicks have become even more likely. But it's always possible for anyone to make a mistake. With the current implementation, even if you immediately realize that you've made a mistake, there is no recourse (other than starting a new bounty, and, aside from the reputation considerations, this still results in a bounty being awarded to the wrong answer).

Comment: Related (MSE): [Should we allow to undo a mistaken bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257105/should-we-allow-to-undo-a-mistaken-bounty)

Comment: I've started a new bounty, I'll award that in 23 hours on that other answer. Don't misclick again going forward.

Comment: Wow, @rene, thanks 0_O.  

toolic, thanks for link

Comment: For historical reference, the (in)correctly bountied question referred by OP: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76168266

Comment: It's in the revision history, for those who *really* want to know, @TheMaster. I intentionally removed it because it's not the focus of this question anymore, and I see no advantage in directing the Meta effect to it.